# Create Parent Maven Project from Existing projects

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I have existing two maven projects, I want to combine them after build into one project.
I have not created these projects module wise, the two projects are separate maven projects.
Below is the POM xml code part from existing projects.

**Project One** pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.olex</groupId>
<artifactId>olex-reg</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

**Project Two** pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.olex</groupId>
<artifactId>olex-qba</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

**Combine Project** pom.xml

```
<groupId>com.olex</groupId>
<artifactId>olex-war</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

I want to combine these projects into one like `olex-war`, A complete project.
After build I want all the code to be copied to this `olex-war` project.
Please suggest / provide hint if anyone aware of such scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want olex-war to get olex-qba and olex-reg dependencies, unpack it and repack it in a new war? Or do you want to have a complete new project including all code from both projects?

Comment: I want to keep olex-qba and olex-reg as separate projects, as they are now. But just want a new project as a combine project of these two (and any other in future like olex-aaa), so when I build that complete main project all get compiled and build as one project named under olex-war.

Comment: What I don't understand, you want a new project or a new artifact to be built? A new project implies that you can modify the sources independently from the old projects. Creating a new artifact will allow you to have the sources in the old repositories aggregated in the new artifact.

Comment: Yes. I want to continue modifying the code from old projects, keeping the old projects separate. But want to create new project where when I build new one, it combines build for old two projects as well. and create a single deploy-able war file.
I have gone through the modular concept in maven as well, but not sure how I can apply now to my existing two different maven projects.

Comment: How do you expect web.xml to work? I mean, in two different war files you have two different web.xml, which one will work? In case you don't need web.xml or any metadata from your original projects, but you only need the Java classes I would try to package these classes in a jar. If this would work I can show you an example.

Comment: @Ale Sequeira
Yes. Your point is correct. The new project will have its own web.xml. But the java classes and view files (like jsp), it will take from existing old two projects. Exactly this I am looking for.
Thanks for understanding the scenario.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55515/discussion-between-mandar-pandit-and-ale-sequeira).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with a pom like this, that extract all the content of your old war files into content directory. Then you could package everything in that directory (except for web.xml and other metadata) in your new war.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.olex</groupId>
  <artifactId>olex-war</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>olex-war Maven Webapp</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>olex-war</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.olex</groupId>
                                <artifactId>olex-qba</artifactId>
                                <version>${project.version}</version>
                                <packaging>war</packaging>
                            </artifactItem>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>com.olex</groupId>
                                <artifactId>olex-reg</artifactId>
                                <version>${project.version}</version>
                                <packaging>war</packaging>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <excludes>WEB-INF/web.xml</excludes>
                        <includes>**/*.class, **/*.jar, **/*.properties</includes>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/content</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What will this do with duplicate files (web.xml comes to mind but there will be other config files as well)?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer, I've added an exclusion to avoid unpacking web.xml, the same should be needed for other files like weblogic.xml.

Comment: And what happens to the ones you forgot? I mean this question literally, what will it do?

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer, if they have the same name the las will stay. One option would be to exclude all the files you don't want. If you want more control you can define exactly what is the content you want from the two war files using include tag, I'm editing my response to show this.

Answer (score 0):

You should combine your projects manually. Many elements (like config files) need manual merging anyway and you want to avoid to accidentally loose something from one project because the other overwrites it quietly.

This would be a horrible mind-dulling task if there were not Version Control Systems to help you with the merging.

First set up a version control system (VCS). It will help in many other situations as well. I recommend git, but if you have another already up and running that should do it just fine, I won't use any fancy specials here.

Then create an empty folder for the new project and copy all the data from the first project into it. Do all replacements as you see fit (web.xml, pom.xml, other config files) and commit it to the VCS.

This will write this version of all files into the VCS and you cannot loose them again, so if you happen to make a mistake, no worries, just revert all changes back to this point.

Then copy the content of the second project over it overwriting everything thats duplicate.

Now you can use the "show differences" feature of your VCS to see what you'll need to merge. Most likely you can do so in a graphic tool so that makes it easy.

Most of them will be "unknown" that is, the new file does not exist in the VCS, yet. Most likely you can just add them to the VCS and be done with them.
More interesting are the ones that are "modified". That means the file already existed and the other project contained them as well. You will have to merge them into a combined version that is from now on valid for your new project.

When you are done you should have all the files (including pom.xml) necessary for the new project ready. Commit them to the VCS to not loose this state in the future.